# Убрать категорую в url wordpress 5,без ошибки 404?

Tags: php, wordpress

убирал с помошью RewriteRule ^(.*?/)category/(.+)$ $1$2 [R=301,L] в .htaccess,но выдете 404 ,в плагине  SEO Yoast   ставил галочку убрать категорию,но таже 404,пробовал No Category Base с ним также 404
на картинках мои настройки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: No Category Base и Yoast работает, нужно просто пермалинки после этого сохранить)

Comment: как и где сохраняются они?

Comment: Настройки - постоянные ссылки

Comment: Название записи https://xn----htbcxngmi.xn--p1ai/sample-post/ так ставил и Произвольно https://xn----htbcxngmi.xn--p1ai 
/%category%/%postname%/
и так не сработало ,на какой пункт ставить галку?

Comment: делал как тут но ,видимо не работает плагин  или ошибка http://wordpressinside.ru/plugins/categorybase/